# Creating a node module for the SailsJS App

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I have a [sails](http://sailsjs.org/documentation) project which has many functionalities .

ex: Address creation, event management, notification, payment and many 
others.

Now I want to make different services for each one of these. As far as my knowledge, I have two ways to do so:

1. Create a [micro service](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) for every service. (Which is not possible to maintain for now)

   **or**
2. Create respective modules.

So, I'm able to create the module for **Notifications** and **Payment**.
But able to understand how can I create a module for address which can  have:

- Module (want to bind with the sails module)
- Controllers
- Routes

I just need a plug and play module for the functionalities which can access the database same way as sails module does.

Few more questions to add on further :

1. Is there any other better method by which this can be achieved ?
2. Can I bind or control the sails controller and the module before sails lift by the node_module?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider making a hook instead

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks